# Why getting this error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'someTable' already exists")"

Tags: python, django

I am getting error like `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'someTable' already exists")`
I want to know reason for getting this type error. 
I ran the following commands on termial

```
1. python manage.py makemigration app
2. python manage.py migrate app
```

When ran migrate then getting the above error.
I solve my problem by running

```
python manage.py migrate --fake app
```

But I want to know why I am getting this error, and how `--fake app` solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The table 'someTable' already exists in your database - either because it's been created by a previous call to `./manage.py syncdb` or because you created it manually (or you used South before and are switching to Django >= 1.7) - and you obviously didn't have any existing django (non-south) migration, so `makemigration` thinks the table has to be created (rightly so sonce that will indeed be the case for someone that install your app from scratch).

Using the `--fake` flag tells `migrate` command to just record the migration has having been applied without effectively applying it, and that's the whole point of this flag: when your app has already been installed (db tables etc) without migrations and you want to start using migrations.

Answer (score 2):

This problem means that `someTable` was created without Django migrations or record about migrations in `django_migrations` was deleted. `--fake` adds record about migrations in `django_migrations` without applying actual migrations.

Record in `django_migrations` contains information about migration: app label, migration name and date when migrations was applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using the MySQL database.

With SQLite, you will need to delete the SQLite.db

All I did when using MySQL as database to handle this was...

1. make migrations `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. drop the database from the mysql shell `mysql> drop database [database name];`
3. create the database from the mysql shell `mysql> create database [database name];`
4. migrate using the `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` command